# Where should I put configuration files?

Tags: ros, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where should I put node configuration files? (e.g. a knowledge base)
What is the "ROS way" to access these files?

I would like to have a node that reads some files in a folder at startup... files that can be modifyed by users.

or there is a better "ROS way" to do that sort of things?

edit:
I'm only interested in wich is the best location where I can put configuration files and wich is the best way to get the path to these files...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143281/where-should-i-put-configuration-files?/) by [Boris_il_forte](https://answers.ros.org/users/8606/boris_il_forte/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2014-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually what works well is providing the file URI as a ROS parameter that you can set via the rosrun command line or in a launch file. You can pair this with putting the actual files in a `foo_bringup` or `foo_config` package, which contains the config (and launch) files. In the launch files you can then use the `<param name='config_folder' value='$(find_package foo_bringup)/config' />` syntax.

There was a question a while back about downloading additional files for a package (and then finding these from within a node), which might contain useful information for you: http://answers.ros.org/question/109761/where-to-download-extra-files-needed-at-runtime/

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2